# Get latest date in multiple join

Tags: sql, join, group-by, sql-order-by

I'm struggling with this one and even though there are some somewhat similar questions on Stack Overflow I can't find the right solution. I have three tables: `categories, topics` and `posts` where I want to join them and show each category in `categories` together with the subject of the latest topic from `topics` that had something posted in it and finally the latest date that post was posted from the `posts` table.

I successfully get everything to display like I want except that I can't get the latest post record from each category.

Here's the query:

```
SELECT c.cat_id, c.cat_name, c.cat_description, t.topic_subject, t.topic_id, p.post_date FROM categories c 
LEFT JOIN topics t ON c.cat_id = t.topic_cat 
LEFT JOIN posts p ON p.post_topic = t.topic_id AND p.post_date = ( SELECT MAX(post_date) as post_date FROM posts WHERE post_topic = t.topic_id ) 
GROUP BY c.cat_id ORDER BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(post_date) DESC
```

I realize it should have something to do with that the `topic_id` in the `WHERE` clause is not the one I'm looking for. ANother one like this:

```
SELECT c.cat_id, c.cat_name, c.cat_description, t.topic_subject, t.topic_id, p.post_date FROM categories c 
LEFT JOIN topics t ON c.cat_id = t.topic_cat AND t.topic_id = ( SELECT post_topic FROM posts ORDER BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(post_date) DESC LIMIT 1 ) 
LEFT JOIN posts p ON p.post_topic = t.topic_id AND p.post_date = ( SELECT MAX(post_date) as post_date FROM posts WHERE post_topic = t.topic_id ) 
GROUP BY c.cat_id ORDER BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(post_date) DESC
```

will obviously only show the right post for the category with the latest post overall in it. How to get the latest post for all of the categories?

Comment: Does the topics table have field post_date?

Comment: nope, the posts table only. They are all connected by their IDs, like cat_id = topic_cat and topic_id = post_topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT c.cat_id, c.cat_name, c.cat_description, tp.topic_subject, tp.topic_id, tp.maxPostDate
FROM categories c 

LEFT JOIN (select t.topic_cat,t.topic_subject,t.topic_id, max(post_date) maxPostDate  from topics t
           LEFT JOIN posts p ON p.post_topic = t.topic_id
           group by t.topic_cat,t.topic_subject,t.topic_id) tp
on (c.cat_id=tp.topic_cat)


where tp.maxPostDate = (select max(post_date) from topics t2
                       LEFT JOIN posts p2 ON p2.post_topic = t2.topic_id
                       where t2.topic_cat=c.cat_id
                       )


ORDER BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(tp.maxPostDate) DESC
```

Note: This query can output for example 2 rows for one category if it has 2 different topics with the same maximum post date.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a lot...would have given you 10 up votes if I could ;)

Comment: But for it to output two, they need to have been posted the very same second, right? Unlikely...

Comment: Yes they need to post 2 posts in different topics of the same category with the same timestamp. Unlikely but not impossible :)

Comment: Any idea how to in the same query also `select` the username from the `users` table `where userID = p.post_by` so the user who posted the latest post in each category also shows up?

Comment: To get username add this sub query column to the main select: '(select username from users where userid=(select post_by from posts p3 where p3.post_topic=tp.topic_id and p3.post_date=tp.maxPostDate))'

Answer (score 0):

First: in your Select queries you must use some agregate functions for the fields that you don't include in the GROUP BY clause.

Now. For gettin the post with max timestamp for each category, you have to make a two steps query. In first step you will get the max timestamp for category and in the second all the other fields. Yes, we'll use cat_id + timestamp as primary key. It could provide some duplicate records for the same cat_id, but it will be very extrange that in real time ocours.

The code will be similar to:

```
SELECT c.cat_id, MAX( p.post_date ) as max_date
into #tmp_table
FROM categories c 
    LEFT JOIN topics t ON c.cat_id = t.topic_cat 
    LEFT JOIN posts p ON p.post_topic = t.topic_id 
GROUP BY c.cat_id 

SELECT * -- what you'll need
from #tmp_table as tmp
    LEFT JOIN categories as c on c.cat_id = tmp.cad_id
    LEFT JOIN topics t ON c.cat_id = t.topic_cat 
    LEFT JOIN posts p ON p.post_topic = t.topic_id AND p.post_date = tmp.max_date
-- order by -- what you'll need
```

It's a solution, 
better one could be nice.